# Django User Registration Form KeyError

Tags: django, keyerror

When requesting a blank RegisterForm, I get a KeyError. I believe that when I click the link on the site, I submit a GET request to the register method and the form1 = RegisterForm() line fires. I believe there is something wrong with my RegisterForm class but I can't figure out what it is. I'm using the User model and UserCreationForm. Any help is greatly appreciated.

KeyError at /profile/pm/register u'username'

Traceback:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/vagrant/project/tmp/user_profile/views.py" in register
  77.       form1 = RegisterForm()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py" in __init__
  97.         self.fields[self._meta.model.USERNAME_FIELD].widget.attrs.update({'autofocus': ''})
```

Exception Type: KeyError at /profile/pm/register
Exception Value: u'username'

views.py

```
def register(request, user_type):
if user_type not in ["pm", "hm"]:
    raise Http404

if request.user.is_authenticated():
    return redirect(reverse('index'))

if user_type == 'hm':
    userTypeChoices = [Profile.RecruiterAgency, Profile.RecruiterInternal, Profile.HiringManager]
else:
    userTypeChoices = [Profile.PMEmployee, Profile.PMContractConsultant, Profile.PMBoth]

if request.method =="POST":
    # accept tos
    if 'accepted_tos' in request.POST:
        return acceptedTOS(request)

    form1 = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    form2 = ProfileForm(request.POST)
    if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
        user = form1.save()

        profile = Profile()
        profile.user_id = user.id
        profile.company = form2.cleaned_data["company"]
        profile.phone = form2.cleaned_data["phone"]
        profile.user_type = form2.cleaned_data["user_type"]
        profile.save()

        if profile.user_type in [Profile.PMEmployee, Profile.PMContractConsultant, Profile.PMBoth]:
            prospect = Prospect(profile=profile)
            prospect.save()
        else:
            employer = Employer(profile=profile)
            employer.save()

        return JsonResponse({'message':'success'})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'message':form2.errors})
else:
    form1 = RegisterForm()
    form2 = ProfileForm()

return render(request, 'profile/register.html', {'form1':form1, 'form2':form2, 'userType':user_type, 'userTypeChoices':userTypeChoices})
```

forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label = "Email")
    first_name = forms.CharField(label = "First name")
    last_name = forms.CharField(label = "Last name")

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ("email", "first_name", "last_name")

def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError('Email already in use.')
    return email

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(RegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.username = self.cleaned_data["email"]
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")

phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

RecruiterAgency = 'ra'
RecruiterInternal = 'ri'
HiringManager = 'hm'
PMEmployee = 'pe'
PMContractConsultant = 'pc'
PMBoth = 'pm'
USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (RecruiterAgency, 'Recruiter - Agency'),
    (RecruiterInternal, 'Recruiter - Internal'),
    (HiringManager, 'Hiring Manager'),
    (PMEmployee, 'PM - Employee'),
    (PMContractConsultant, 'PM - Contract / Consultant'),
    (PMBoth, 'PM - Both'),
)
user_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES, default=RecruiterAgency)

company = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

bio = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

accepted_tos = models.BooleanField(default=False)

profile_photo = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="avatar")

def __str__(self):
    return "%s's profile" % self.user.email

class Prospect(models.Model):
profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name="profile_prospects")
RestrictedCompany = models.ForeignKey(RestrictedCompany, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name="company_prospects")
badge = models.ManyToManyField(Badge, blank=True, related_name="badge_prospects")
certification = models.ManyToManyField(Certification, blank=True, related_name="certification_prospects")

LargestProject1 = 'lp1'
LargestProject2 = 'lp2'
LargestProject3 = 'lp3'
LargestProject4 = 'lp4'
LargestProject5 = 'lp5'
LARGEST_PROJECT_CHOICES = (
    (LargestProject1, '$1-100,000'),
    (LargestProject2, '$100,001-$500,000'),
    (LargestProject3, '$500,001-$1,000,000'),
    (LargestProject4, '$1,000,001-$5,000,000'),
    (LargestProject5, '$5,000,001+'),
)
largest_project = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=LARGEST_PROJECT_CHOICES, default=LargestProject1)

add_to_pool = models.BooleanField(default=False)

LargestTeam1 = 'lt1'
LargestTeam2 = 'lt2'
LargestTeam3 = 'lt3'
LargestTeam4 = 'lt4'
LargestTeam5 = 'lt5'
LargestTeam6 = 'lt6'
LARGEST_TEAM_CHOICES = (
    (LargestTeam1, '0-5'),
    (LargestTeam2, '6-10'),
    (LargestTeam3, '11-20'),
    (LargestTeam4, '21-50'),
    (LargestTeam5, '51-100'),
    (LargestTeam6, '100+'),
)
largest_team = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=LARGEST_TEAM_CHOICES, default=LargestTeam1)

Contract = 'ct'
FullTimeEmployee = 'fe'
Both = 'bo'
Position_Type_CHOICES = (
    (Contract, 'Contract'),
    (FullTimeEmployee, 'Full-Time Employee'),
    (Both, 'Both'),
)
position_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=Position_Type_CHOICES, default=Contract)

resume = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="resume")

EntryLevel = 'el'
Junior = 'jn'
Professional = 'pr'
TIER_CHOICES = (
    (EntryLevel, 'Entry-Level'),
    (Junior, 'Junior'),
    (Professional, 'Professional'),
)
tier = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=TIER_CHOICES, default=EntryLevel)

billable_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

annual_salary = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

total_years_exp = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return "%s" % self.profile.user.email

class Employer(models.Model):
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name="profile_employers")

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.profile.user.email
```

Comment: whats in UserCreationForm? please post some code

Comment: Its one of the built in forms: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/forms/

Comment: post your User model

Comment: Yes! Please post your User model as it is very likely you have a field called `username` which is your `USERNAME_FIELD` too, but that field is not part of your form. This is the case for the default in-built User model

Comment: Added models.py. I'm using the standard Django User model so maybe there's something I'm missing in there? Thanks for looking at this!

Comment: Your problem is that the `UserCreationForm` expects the user's username field (in this case 'username') to be a form field ([source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L97)). If you are just starting out, you might want to switch to a custom user model, and use `email` as the username field (see [the example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) in the docs). If this isn't a new project, then switching to a custom user model is extremely difficult, and you'll have to modify your form to prevent the error.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't a new project. What I'm trying to do is ask the user for their email address and then pass that into the username field (without explicitly defining the email field as the username). How would I do that? Do I change the "email" field on the RegisterForm to be called "username" instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments were correct and very helpful! I needed to rename the "email" field on the RegisterForm to "username":

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
username = forms.EmailField(label = "Email")
first_name = forms.CharField(label = "First name")
last_name = forms.CharField(label = "Last name")

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ("username", "first_name", "last_name")

def clean_email(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data['email']
    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError('Email already in use.')
    return username

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(RegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.username = self.cleaned_data["email"]
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

Answer (score 0):

You have come across [this issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27111) where the `UserCreationForm` crashes if `USERNAME_FIELD` (in your case `username`) is not a form field.

The issue only affects Django 1.10, it doesn't affect earlier versions of Django. It will be fixed in the upcoming [Django 1.10.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10.1/) release.